# Weibel HA p. 13: how to construct the map $\operatorname{coker}\partial_{n+1} \to \ker \partial_n$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homological-algebra

In Weibel's *An Introduction to Homological Algebra,* p. 13, the author claims that a short exact sequence of chain complexes $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$ induces the following commutative diagram:

[image]

My question is:

> How is the map $\operatorname{coker} \partial_{n+1} \to \ker \partial_{n-1}$ induced by the differential map?

I know that we can go along the other direction:
$$\ker \partial_n \to A_n \to \operatorname{coker}\partial_{n+1}$$
It is easy to verify that
$$H_n = \operatorname{im}(\ker \partial_n \to \operatorname{coker}\partial_{n+1})$$
On p. 14 the book claims that
$$H_n = \ker(\operatorname{coker}\partial_{n+1} \to \ker \partial_{n-1})$$
How do we derive this result?

Comment: I don't see anything resembling this claim in p.13 of my book. Can you give the full context?

Comment: The map you seek is given by applying $\partial_n$ on representatives. Which part of this being a well-defined map are you struggling to show?

Comment: @AlexProvost It is the discussion just after Exercise 1.3.3. He is using the snake lemma to construct the long exact sequence of the homology.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about posting this question. The reason that I struggled to find the map was that I confused $\ker\partial_{n}$ with $\ker\partial_{n-1}$ as I was reading another material quoting this result.

Since $\operatorname{im} \partial_{n} \subseteq \ker \partial_{n-1}$, $\partial_n$ factors through the kernel of $\partial_{n-1}$. Then since $\operatorname{im} \partial_{n+1}\subseteq \ker \partial_{n}$, by the universal property of quotient, $\partial_n$ factors through the cokernel $\operatorname{coker}\partial_{n+1}$. In such way we get a well-defined map $\tilde \partial_n: \operatorname{coker}\partial_{n+1} \to \ker \partial_{n-1}$, as shown in the diagram:[image: 1]

Now $\ker \tilde \partial_n = \dfrac{\ker\partial_n}{\operatorname{im} \partial_{n+1}} = H_n$ and $\operatorname{coker}\tilde\partial_n = \dfrac{\ker\partial_{n-1}}{\operatorname{im}\tilde \partial_n} = \dfrac{\ker\partial_{n-1}}{\operatorname{im}\partial_n} = H_{n-1}$.